# how to apply in one line this widgets in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

need apply in my index.html file this social media icons and menu icons in bootstrap

```html
    <ul class="social-media list-inline" align="right">
      <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-facebook"></span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-envelope"></span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-twitter"></span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-youtube"></span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-instagram"></span></a></li>
     </ul>
     <!--end social-->
     <a href="#fh5co-offcanvass" class="js-fh5co-nav-toggle fh5co-nav-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#fh5co-navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar"><span>Menu</span> <i></i></a>
```

I need In one line....

Comment: What do you mean? Do you mean align all the icons horizontally?

Comment: Give ul li{display:inline-block;} @Lion

Comment: yes you are correct @Raptor

Comment: @Dhaarani it's not the bootstrap way to do so.

Comment: @ Raptor okay. I will update without bootstrap sample code.

Answer (score 1):

For Bootstrap 3:

```
<ul class="list-inline social-media">
  <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-facebook"></span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-envelope"></span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-twitter"></span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-youtube"></span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-instagram"></span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Ref: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#inline

If you are using bootstrap 4:

```
<ul class="list-inline social-media">
  <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-facebook"></span></a></li>
  <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-envelope"></span></a></li>
  <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-twitter"></span></a></li>
  <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-youtube"></span></a></li>
  <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-instagram"></span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Ref: http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/content/typography/#inline

Just make sure that your `.social-media` class's style is not affecting it to appear as block.

Comment: my social media is working well I need put social media with My menu words horizontaly @Kalpesh Patel

Comment: In that case, you can give display:inline or inline-block to your Menu word. ie `a` tag

Answer (score 0):

The are more than one way to make them display horizontally. Have a look at display property in CSS.

- `display: inline;` - displays in a single line, doesn't share the height with siblings
- `display: inline-block;` - displays in a single line, shares the height with siblings
- `display: inline-flex;`- displays in a single line, shares the height and width with siblings

```css
ul.social-media {
  display: inline-flex;
}

div.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<span class="container">
<ul class="social-media list-inline" align="right">
      <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-facebook"></span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-envelope"></span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-twitter"></span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-youtube"></span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-instagram"></span></a></li>
     </ul>
     <!--end social-->
     <a href="#fh5co-offcanvass" class="js-fh5co-nav-toggle fh5co-nav-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#fh5co-navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar"><span>Menu</span> <i></i></a>
</span>
```

Comment: I need make horizontaly social media icons with Menu words

Comment: menu words in the sense? could you elaborate it?

Comment: i think menu should be in same line as the icons

Answer (score 0):

You correctly add bootstrap js and bootstrap css.

```css
ul.social-media {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="social-media list-inline" align="right">
  <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-facebook"></span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-envelope"></span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-twitter"></span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-youtube"></span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-instagram"></span></a></li>
 </ul>
 <!--end social-->
 <a href="#fh5co-offcanvass" class="js-fh5co-nav-toggle fh5co-nav-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#fh5co-navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar"><span>Menu</span> <i></i></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without Bootstrap.

```css
ul.social-media li,ul{display:inline-block;padding:0px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="social-media list-inline" align="right">
  <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-facebook"></span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-envelope"></span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-twitter"></span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-youtube"></span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-instagram"></span></a></li>
 </ul>
 <!--end social-->
 <a href="#fh5co-offcanvass" class="js-fh5co-nav-toggle fh5co-nav-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#fh5co-navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar"><span>Menu</span> <i></i></a>
```